# While read line with grep

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, grep

I am trying to report lines found using grep and while.

I know you can use the following to compare a list of strings from inputs.txt and find them in your target file like so:

```
grep -f inputs.txt file_to_check
```

What I want is to read each line of the inputted strings and grep them individual in a loop.

So I have tried the following methods:

```
cat inputs.txt | while read line; do if grep "$line" filename_to_check; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"; fi; done
```

This returns nothing when I redirect the output to a file.

```
while read line
do
if grep "$line" file_to_check
  then echo "found"
else 
  echo "not found"
fi
done < inputs.txt
```

Same as the first one but from what I found is better to do.

I know it iterates line by line because I can replace grep with echo $line and it prints each line; but either method doesn't return anything like grep -f above, instead it shows:

```
not found
not found
not found
.
. etc.
```

So what I'm looking for is something where it will iterate through each line and check it via grep using an if statement to determine if grep has actually found it or not. I know I may not have all proper logic but the output for what I want should look something like:

```
Found *matching line in file_to_check* 
Found *matching line in file_to_check*
Not Found $line *(string that does not match)*
.
. etc.
```

Comment: read test command or `[ `

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `&&` and `||` operators :

```
while read line; do
         grep -q "$line" file_to_check  && echo "$line found in file_to_check" || echo "$line not found in file_to_check"
done < inputfile > result.txt
```

The `-q` parameter of the grep just outputs a status code :

- if `$line` is found, it outpouts `0` (True) the command after `&&` will be evaluated
- if not found, it outputs `1` (False) the command after `||` will evaluated

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your final solution into

```
# Do not need this thanks to tr: file=$(dos2unix inputs.txt)

# Use -r so a line with backslashes will be showed like you want
while read -r line
do 
   # Not empty? Check with test -n
   if [ -n "$(grep "${line}" filename)" ]; then 
      echo "found: ${line}"
   else
      echo "not found: ${line}"
   fi 
done < <(tr -d "\r" < "${file}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your if statement is pretty free form, you might need to clean it up a bit for bash to be able to read it. For example:

```
if [ "$(grep "$line" file_to_check)" != "" ]; then
    echo "found:     $line"
else
    echo "not found: $line"
fi
```

This if statement will evaluate true if the grep command finds the line, because if it does it will spit the line out and will not be equal to "", or an empty string.

Comment: Thanks I found the file special carriage returns that grep did not know how to handle. So I copied the content into another test file via VIM and it reported what I wanted.

@Skyler, your example helped but it gave some weird output and even test it with my new file that worked after testing. The out put using:

while read line; do 
if [ $(grep "$line" file_to_check) != "" ]; then
    echo "found:     $line"
else
    echo "not found: $line"
fi
done < inputs.txt 

gave


**bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
not found: item1
bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
not found: item2** etc.

Comment: My apologies @Joshua, the $(command) should have been surrouded by double quotes, answer updated.

Comment: @Joshua If the file contains carriage returns, use `dos2unix` to convert it to normal Unix newlines.

Comment: Thanks, that was my bad on the double quotes there. I think I have solved my solution and will look into dos2unix. I started using **cat inputs.txt | tr -d '\r' > newinputs.txt** which worked well too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final solution:

```
file=$(dos2unix inputs.txt)
new_file=$file

while read line
do 
  if [ "$(grep "$line" filename)" != "" ]
    then echo "found: $line"
  else echo "not found: $line"
  fi 
done <$new_file
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Do not do `if [ "$(grep "$line" filename)" != "" ]`.  Just do `if grep -q "$line" filename`.